# WinRT with VS2010 on Win8?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, windows-8, winrt-xaml

To what extent is it possible and legal to developer WinRT applications with VS2010 Pro?

On the one side, I think it *should* be perfectly possible and legal to create an HTML5/CSS/JavaScript WinRT App with VS2010 Pro since you can *probably* do so using Win 8 Notepad.  On the other side, I think it might be difficult and possibly illegal to create an C# WinRT App via VS2010 Pro since doing so might require the user to circumvent intentional limitations of the VS2010 Pro software.

In the old days, the user just bought a stand alone compiler and she/he was free to link it against whatever libraries she/he choose.  In this way, she/he didn't have to upgrade her/his compiler anytime she wanted a newer version of MFC or *.NET.  These days, the IDE seems to be married to the compiler so I'm not sure if the user is allowed to use older IDEs (such as VS2010) to link against newer libraries like those offered in WinRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx).

> You can use the Windows SDK, along with your chosen development
>   environment, to write Windows Store apps (only on Windows 8)...

So it's clearly legal.  I haven't tested it, but I'm going to guess that you can probably do the code side of things in VS 2010, but VS 2010 isn't setup to do Windows Store UI so xaml, html5 etc probably won't work.

It's probably much easier to simply use Visual Studio 2012 express.

Comment: Mr. mydogisbox.  Your answer sounds promising to me.  If I had rep, I would +1 you.  I think the Windows SDK could help but Microsoft *seems* to say: "The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment."  If you combine that Microsoft statement with Mr. Copsey's statement "...the language needed changing...", then I'm not sure if it will work for me.  I guess I could go ahead and install VS2012 Express for Web to do compile work and then use VS2010 Pro or EMACS for text editing.  It would be a bit clunky, but it sounds like it would be legal and work.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @AnonymousHippieCoder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh924768.aspx Prerequisites for both are VS 2012.  It looks like MSBuild is now part of VS.

Answer (score 0):

> To what extent is it possible and legal to developer WinRT applications with VS2010 Pro?

It is not (directly).  The APIs and the packaging tools will not be available in VS 2010.

While you could potentially do this yourself, it seems far simpler to just install [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8) and use it.

> These days, the IDE seems to be married to the compiler so I'm not sure if the user is allowed to use older IDEs (such as VS2010) to link against newer libraries like those offered in WinRT

It's more than just newer libraries - there's an entire new runtime, and the language needed changing in order to work with it.

Comment: Mr. Copsey.  Thank you for your quality feedback.  If I had rep, I would +1 you.  I did not realize the C# language had changed going from *.NET 4.0 to WinRT.  I understand the argument for VS2012 Express, but I'm not sure if VS2012 Express supports macros and extensions.  Also, I'm not sure if VS2012 Express will let me mix Web and WinRT Projects in the same solution.

Comment: @AnonymousHippieCoder VS2012 dropped macros entirely.  The express editions are limited in various ways, as well, so you'd have to check if it'd meet your requirements, or if an upgrade to VS would be required in your scenario.