# Application that works on pc and mobile

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, mobile, windows-7, microsoft-metro

I have to create an application with metro design on vs2010 and windows 7.
The application should work both on pc and device without internet.

Initially i though of wpf but i do not know if it works on Mobile.

Please let me know how i can develop once such standalone application for
both device and PC also

Comment: You're looking for WinRT XAML, you need Visual Studio 2012 for that. BTW, non-Windows devices (such as Android devices and iOS devices) of course do not support "Metro" style apps. That is a Windows concept. You can create an app using WinRT XAML and it will run on PC Windows 8 and on RT version of Windows 8 (Windows Phone 8 and Surface Tablets)

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. is there any way to create it using the 2010? because our comp dont have 2012 but they asked me to do so. Also if as per you suggestion i create the appliction on 2012 will i t work on earlier operating systems like xp and windows 7.Application need to run on windows device only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16152290/643085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a single platform that targets both PC and Phone...although, the presumption is that Windows Phone and Windows Store applications are moving toward a unified foundation.

Windows Store applications unfortunately don't run on Windows 7. Only Windows 8 and above, but the advantage is they work with the desktop version as well as the tablet version of windows.

If you want to target windows 7 and say windows phone as well, your best bet is to use portable class libraries to create a common "core" for the application. And use WPF for the desktop which has a lot in common with XAML for Windows Phone.

If you want to target windows phone 8, you have to use Visual Studio 2012 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but in case anyone is still blindfolded, there is [UWP](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/getstarted).

Furthermore, if you want to have XAML and C# deployed as native apps in a variety of platforms (UWP, Droid, iOS, WinPhone), be sure to check out [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform), which now belongs to Microsoft, and follows the awesomeness of open-source MIT just as the entire .NET does now.